# Add an attribute to a Rails model using attr_accessor (or other function)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I created a Rails model, let's say `Car`. I added an attribute to it (not to be saved in the DB) called `age`.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :age 
end
```

If I try to print out the attributes of my car, `age` does not show up. I found out because attr_accessor is only defining an instance variable.

```
> my_car = Car.first
> my_car.age = 500
> puts my_car
```

How can I add an attribute to the record itself that is not persisted to the DB?

Comment: you just answered your own question.

Comment: @sevenseacat thanks, wasn't sure if that was it. Updated question, since I still need to know how to add an attribute to the record without persisting it to db.

Comment: you already have - you use `attr_accessor`. Just because it isn't output in the `inspect` output, doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: I do `my_car.to_json` and I need `age` to be included.

Comment: hooray, now we get the actual problem. Define `as_json` in your model to specify the required json representation of the model.

Comment: This question is not useful in it's current form. `attr_accessor` **does** add a field which isn't saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Referce of [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

Render age to json with methods option.

```
my_car = Car.first
my_car.age = 500
puts my_car.to_json(:methods => :age)
```